# standard deviation as matlab performance function

Tags: matlab, neural-network, standard-deviation

I Would like to set neural network performance function to standard deviation using net.performfcn.
Using `help(net.performFcn)`, seems there are these possibilities:

```
net.performfcn = 'mse'
net.performfcn = 'msereg'
net.performfcn = 'mae'
net.performfcn = 'sse'
net.performfcn = 'sae'
```

no standard deviation in this list!
do I have to implement it myself or there is a quick way that I am not aware of?

Comment: Using the standard deviation as a measure of performance is not something I would ever recommend.  You could have output results from your network that are completely different than the *a priori* labels, yet those labels could have a very low standard deviation among them.  I'm not sure what your aim is to use the standard deviation is here but I would never use it to assess performance.